# CodeIgniter htaccess not redirecting to WWW

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

my CI htaccess not redirecting from non www to www...

```
    RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L] 


<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>
```

where is the problem? Also it should not remove params which is working now (index.php/ removing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change order of your rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}  [R=301,L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} system|application
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Try in a different browser to avoid 301 caching.

Comment: Do you want `non-www to www` OR `www to non-www`?

Comment: ok I have edited the answer based on your comment. Try it out ina new browser.